# I have a Kotlin async task that performs a network call. I would like to pass the method that the task should execute at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin

This is a Kotlin Android app using GRPC. What I am trying to avoid is having multiple GrpcTask classes or doInBackGround functions, one for each network call. For example Login, logout, get some data etc... in the example below the function sayhello is hard coded. Is there a way to pass different functions as a parameter? And have different return types. I am not sure how to approach this in Kotlin so I really haven't attempted anything yet.

```
  override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Int?): String? {
                val host = params[0]
                val message = params[1]
                val portStr = params[2]
                val port = if (TextUtils.isEmpty("50002")) 0 else Integer.valueOf("50002")
                return try {
                    channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("127.0.0.1", 50002).usePlaintext().build()
                    val stub = emeraldSRVGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel)
                /*I would like to make this section dynamic*/
                    val request = HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName(message).build()
                    val reply = stub.sayHello(request)
               /* */
                    reply.message
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    val sw = StringWriter()
                    val pw = PrintWriter(sw)
                    e.printStackTrace(pw)
                    pw.flush()

                    "Failed... : %s".format(sw)
            }
```

Comment: FYI, AsyncTask is deprecated in Android 11+. It will still work, though. Coroutines or java.util.concurrent are the recommended preferred methods.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, You can do something like that:

```
fun <Input, Output> doInBackground(
    vararg params: Int?,
    inputHandler: (Array<Int?>) -> Input,
    outputHandler: (Input) -> Output): Output {
    val host = params[0]
    val message = params[1]
    val portStr = params[2]

    return outputHandler(inputHandler(arrayOf(host, message, portStr)))
}
```

where `Input`, `Output` could be any type you like.
Here inputHandler, outputHandler are functions required.